# Как найти нужный словарь, если есть value

Tags: python, pandas, словари, dict

У меня есть список, состоящий из словарей. В каждом словаре есть 2 пары key-value: id и phrase.
Есть dataframe, который содержит некие фразы. Мне нужно по фразе найти id. Пример словаря:

```
{
"id: "Hello_mother"
"phrase": "Привет, мама!"
}
```

Как это условно должно работать:

```
input: Привет, мама!
#некий алгоритм поиска
result: 'Hello_mother'
```

Надеюсь, доступно пояснил)

Answer (score 1):

Ну вот так, например. Сделать сначала словарь формата "фраза->id" и потом искать в нём:

```py
dict_list = [{
"id": "Hello_mother",
"phrase": "Привет, мама!"
}]

phrase_dict = {d["phrase"]: d["id"] for d in dict_list}
for phrase in ["Привет, мама!", "Что-то непонятное"]:
    print(phrase, '->', phrase_dict.get(phrase, "Значение не найдено!"))
```

Вывод:

```
Привет, мама! -> Hello_mother
Что-то непонятное -> Значение не найдено!
```

Answer (score 1):

если у вас фразы хранятся в датафрейме, то что мешает хранить ваши пары id-phrase тоже в датафрейме. тогда задача решается через merge, как-то так:

```
dict_list = [{"id": "Hello_mother", "phrase": "Привет, мама"},
             {'id': 'Hello_dad', 'phrase': 'Привет, папа'},
             {'id': 'Bye', 'phrase': 'Пока'}]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(dict_list)
>>> df1
'''
             id        phrase
0  Hello_mother  Привет, мама
1     Hello_dad  Привет, папа
2           Bye          Пока
'''

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'phrase':['Привет, мама','Привет, папа','Как дела','Пока']}
>>> df2
'''
         phrase
0  Привет, мама
1  Привет, папа
2      Как дела
3          Пока
'''

res = df2.merge(df1, how='left')
>>> res
'''
         phrase            id
0  Привет, мама  Hello_mother
1  Привет, папа     Hello_dad
2      Как дела           NaN
3          Пока           Bye
```